# Magento 2.4.4: which is the table in Magento DB to update the URLs

Tags: magento2, database

We have a staging site which starts with `magento2.` I did recently dump the Magento DB from the live site into that of dev site because of which all links on the staging site redirect to the live site. I used to run the following SQL in the past to update the URLs in the dev Magento DB, but they don't seem to work this time. Could you please tell me if they are still valid or what needs to be changed?

```
UPDATE `core_config_data` SET `value` = 'https://magento2.perfectmakeupmirrors.com/' WHERE `core_config_data`.`config_id` = 2;
UPDATE `core_config_data` SET `value` = 'https://magento2.perfectmakeupmirrors.com/' WHERE `core_config_data`.`config_id` = 3;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `config_id` column is an auto_incrementing ID and is not necessarily the correct row to update for the base URLs.

If you just want to update the secure+unsecure base URLs then the following SQL should be used.

```
UPDATE `magento`.`core_config_data` SET `value` = 'https://magento.test/' WHERE `path` = `web/secure/base_url`;
UPDATE `magento`.`core_config_data` SET `value` = 'https://magento.test/' WHERE `path` = `web/unsecure/base_url`;
```

*If this is the correct answer please mark it "accepted" as it makes it easier for others with the same issue to find the answer.*

Comment: Craig, could you please provide links to some documentation on this? Is this what Magento instructs us to do?

Comment: When changing URLs locally I do it via the DB as I find it quicker that way. Adobe's developer documentation provides instructions for setting it via the CLI here https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/installation-guide/tutorials/store.html

Comment: Thank you very much for this

Comment: Update went successful and I see it in the table. Do I need to clear cache or something because the dev site still is redirecting to live the site?

Comment: Yes clearing the cache should sort that. The config is cached so that Magento does not need to merge the DB and XML config on every request.

Comment: Thanks this is fixed. I've another problem with admin login that is giving HTTP error 500 while the storefront is working fine. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please tell me how to see Apache error log.